# SASS child rule setting inside based on parent under?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I've not a trivial question. Can we make a style rule for `.child` class in case if `global` class `.some_parent` is present inside the DOM tree above? So, I need to put this work by maximum compact syntax, without class rewriting for separate `global` class. But this is doesn't work:

```
 // sass

 .child {
  :global(.some_parent_class_for_this_child) { // if we it present in DOM tree above then  @media is firing for .child class

    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      flex: 3;
    }
  }
 }
```

I know that this is a illegal syntax, but maybe you have as close as possible working example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the next approach:

```
.child {
  // some rules

  @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .some_parent_class_for_this_child & {
     // some rules for child once tn have .parent class above themself
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for **@at-root**

```
.child {
  @at-root{
    .parent & {
      @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        flex: 3;
      }
    }
  }
}
```